# отсортировать строки в файле по заданным полям

Tags: python, сортировка, list

у меня есть фаил с в котором есть данные

```
 1. Jack Ohio 23 10
 2. Mary Carra 26 29
 3. Jerry White 3 12
```

нужно сортировать список в алфавитном порядке, вывести имя фамилию и последние данные 
Jack Ohio 10

```
    inputFile = open("input", 'r', encoding='utf8')
lineList = inputFile.readlines()
lineList.sort()

print('The input in alphabetical order below :')
for line in lineList:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Comment: @КириллМалышев не получается удалить первое число из всего списка

Comment: если у вас не получается данные из строки достать, то именно об этом и спрашивайте ("как распознать заданный формат").  Зная как достать данные, можно спросить как отсортировать строки в файле по заданному ключу (вопрос об использовании key параметра у sort() метода—никак не связан с "как распознать формат" вопросом). Разбивая задачу на более составляющие, более полезные вопросы могут получиться, которые применимы к большему кругу людей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так, проверить сейчас не могу, поэтому могут быть ошибки :)

```
with open("input", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
   lst = [x.rstrip('\n').split()[1:] for x in f]
lst = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: x[1])
print('The input in alphabetical order below :')
for line in lst:
    print(line)
```

Comment: спасибо, с небольшой доработкой разобралась